# How to make a simple check like unless current_user on favorites work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, conditional-statements

I am building an app where a user can add a room to favorites. It works but it also duplicates the relationship multiple times. For example, someone can favorite the same room multiple times. Therefore I wanted to implement a check in the controller unfortunately I am getting this error:

**How can I make this work?**

[image]

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
 before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :favorite]

  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @room unless current_user.rooms.exists?(room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'You favorited #{@room.listing_name}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@room.listing_name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end

  private
    def set_room
      @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :rooms do
    put :favorite, on: :member
  end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_room_path(@room, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
  <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_room_path(@room, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does your user model and schema (migration) look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `User` model has many favorites, just fix typo:

`current_user.favorites << @room unless current_user.favorites.exists?(@room)`

Comment: Thanks allot! I need to concentrate more on the details!